# Referring to the source table name as a variable from models in dbt

Tags: dbt

I have declared a variable inside dbt_project.yml as

```
vars:
    deva: CEMD_RAW
```

and i am using this inside my models file as

```
 select *
from {{ source("{{ var('deva')}}", 'table_name') }}
```

but when i compile the file it says source named '{{ var('deva') }}.table_name' was not found. What is the correct way to refer the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Once you're in your Jinja 'double curlies', you don't need to nest another set off curlies in it, aka [Don't Nest Your Curlies](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/dont-nest-your-curlies).

The correct way to do this would be:

```sql
select *
from {{ source(var('deva'), 'table_name') }}
```